# How do I split a branch up into several parallel branches off the same root?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

A feature request (`tooBigFeature`) has spiraled into a 100-commit, 50-file PR, which, at the end of review, engineering has decided it wants in 10 5-file PRs (`tinyFeatureChunk-01`, `tinyFeatureChunk-02`... etc) - all off a common single commit on our master branch `chucknorrisbranch` (which was just pulled into the `tooBigFeature` branch, of course) so that in case of emergency it can roll back smaller PRs.

Assume that all changes `tooBigFeature` are functionally independent, and that splitting will cause no problems aside from partial, error-free diminution of the feature's completeness in production.

How do I do this ? Are there any tools to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like quite an annoying task to be asked to do but one approach would be to

- `git reset chucknorrisbranch` to get all your work ready to be staged
- 10 times repeat:

  - `git checkout -b tinyFeatureChunk-0<index> chucknorrisbranch`
  - `git add <5 files>`
  - `git commit -m "Some message"`

A quick Ruby script that would do the above might look like this

```rb
`git status --porcelain`.chomp.split("\n").each_slice(5).with_index { |lines, index|
  `git checkout -b tinyFeatureChunk-0#{index + 1} chucknorrisbranch`
  lines.each { |line| `git add #{line[3..]}` }
  `git commit -m "some message"`
}
```